# Run mysql query to join 3 or more tables into one major table

Tags: mysql

I currently want to know how or is it possible to join 2 or more tables with selected column in each table and join them into 1 master table under the same schema in mysql workbench.

The problem is I have 3 different tables (column 1 epoch date time, column 2 date time, column 3 data for table 1). The 2nd table similar to first table ((column 1 epoch date time, column 2 date time, column 3 data for table 2) etc.

Is it possible to join data from table1 and column 3 and table 2 column 3 into one master table? with respect to the date and time?

**Table 1**

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EpochTime1 | DateTime1 | Data 1 |
| EpochTime2 | DateTime2 | Data 2 |

**Table 2**

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EpochTime1 | DateTime1 | Data 1 |
| EpochTime2 | DateTime2 | Data 2 |

**Master Table**

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EpochTime1 | DateTime1 | Data 1 | Data 1 |
| EpochTime2 | DateTime2 | Data 2 | Data 2 |

**My mysql query i tried**

```
INSERT ignore INTO amacc.amain2 (datetimec,V1,V2,V3,C1,C2,C3)
SELECT c2.datetimex and c1.datetimed,
       c2.VoltageAB, 
       c2.VoltageBC,
       c2.VoltageCA,
       c1.VoltageAB,
       c1.CurrentB,
       c1.CurrentC
FROM amacc.officialphsvoltage0002 AS c2
INNER JOIN amacc.officialphsvoltagecurrent0001 AS c1 
  ON c1.datetimed = c2.datetimex
```

How to I join 2 or more different table into 1 master table with respect to the date and time of all tables?

Comment: 1) What happened when you tried that query? 2) Could you make it so your example tables and your query use the same columns, please? That will make it easier to understand what you're asking for. 3) Are you sure `c2.datetimex and c1.datetimed` is correct?